# MigraDoc: Forcing embed tables to break at logical points

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have a large form I'm transforming into a PDF.  The first 1/6th of it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCiuj.png

The number of entered fields however, varies from 1 to 20 per section, and I need to be able to make this document break pages intelligently.  My plan was to originally draw the tables piece by piece and just manage the Y-coordinate by grabbing the number of rows in all previous tables.   This worked, but falls apart when I get to a page break, and I start needing some semi-complicated logic to make it work, and it's the kind of logic that gets messier and messier with each additional table added.

My second plan was to reproduce the table structure of the HTML document in the PDF, which I  manage to do successfully...

```
private void DrawPDF()
{
    Document tDoc = new Document();
    MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Style style = tDoc.Styles["Normal"];
    style.Font.Name = tPdfFont;
    style.Font.Size = 10;
    Section tSec = tDoc.AddSection();

    MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table masterTable = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table();
    masterTable = tSec.AddTable();
    masterTable.Borders.Visible = false;

    Column leftColumn = masterTable.AddColumn("365pt");
    Column spacer = masterTable.AddColumn("10pt");
    Column rightColumn = masterTable.AddColumn("365pt");

    Row tFS = masterTable.AddRow();
    Cell tCell = tFS.Cells[0];

    //
    // Farm Assets Column
    //
    {
        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table tAssetsTable = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table();
        tAssetsTable.Borders.Visible = false;
        Column tColumn = tAssetsTable.AddColumn("365pt");
        tCell.Elements.Add(tAssetsTable);



        //
        // Current Farm Assets
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  // Drawn 10 times to force it to draw over the 1st page.
        {
            Section thisSection = tDoc.AddSection();
            Row tAssetsRow = tAssetsTable.AddRow();
            Cell tAssetsCell = tAssetsRow.Cells[0];

            MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table table = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table();
            table = thisSection.AddTable();
            table.Borders.Width = 0.2;
            table.Rows.LeftIndent = 0;

            Column columnData = table.AddColumn("295pt");
            columnData.Borders.Left.Visible = false;
            Column columnValue = table.AddColumn("70pt");

            Row rowA = table.AddRow();
            rowA.Shading.Color = Color.FromRgbColor((byte)255, Color.Parse("0xa2a2d2"));
            rowA.Cells[0].AddParagraph("CURRENT FARM ASSETS");
            rowA.Cells[1].AddParagraph("$ Value");
            rowA.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

            Row row1 = table.AddRow();
            row1.Borders.Bottom.Visible = false;
            row1.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Cash: Savings: ($" + MP.FormFinancialStatement.CurrentStaticAssets.Savings + ") Checking: ($" + MP.FormFinancialStatement.CurrentStaticAssets.Checking + ")");
            row1.Cells[1].AddParagraph(MP.FormFinancialStatement.CurrentStaticAssets.CashTotal);
            row1.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

            Row row2 = table.AddRow();
            row2.Borders.Bottom.Visible = false;
            row2.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Invest: Time Cret $" + MP.FormFinancialStatement.CurrentStaticAssets.TimeCret + " Other: $" + MP.FormFinancialStatement.CurrentStaticAssets.OtherInvestments + "");
            row2.Cells[1].AddParagraph(MP.FormFinancialStatement.CurrentStaticAssets.InvestTotal);
            row2.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

            Row row3 = table.AddRow();
            row3.Borders.Bottom.Visible = false;
            row3.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Replacement Account");
            row3.Cells[1].AddParagraph(MP.FormFinancialStatement.CurrentStaticAssets.ReplacementAccount);
            row3.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

            Row row4 = table.AddRow();
            row4.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Accouts and Notes Recievable");
            row4.Cells[1].AddParagraph(MP.FormFinancialStatement.CurrentStaticAssets.AccountsNotesReceivable);
            row4.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

            MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table clone = (MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table)table.Clone();

            tAssetsCell.Elements.Add(clone);
        }
    }

    MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(tDoc);
    docRenderer.PrepareDocument();
    docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, 30, 85, "740pt", masterTable);
}
```

But alas, this does not actually break pages correctly.  I tried sectioning off each individual table, hoping that'd do page break magic, but it does not.

How can I structure this to allow for good page breaks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the KeepWith property of the table rows to keep blocks together on one page. Only use this for chunks that will surely fit on one page.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6831048/1015447
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327228/1015447